# Simulink: Indexing from a Constant block with array

Tags: constants, simulink

I could swear that I have seen a constant block in Simulink with a vector in its value field and that the effect was that on each simulation time step, Simulink would index the next value in that array and output it on the Constant block's output (see picture below).  So the output of the constant block  (in the picture below) would be 1, then 2, then 3, then 4.

[image: Simulink screen capture]

However, the effect is (regardless of the value of "interpret vector parameters as 1-d"), that only the first value in the Constant block's array is output from it.

I'm I mistaken? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *haven't* seen the `Constant` block behave that way, because it doesn't behave that way.  If you want the signal to change then you need to use a block that allows/forces you to also specify a time vector of points indicating when the input values change, such as something like the `From Workspace` block.

The way you have your model set up, the `Constant` output is a 4 element vector, as is the output of the `Product` block.

Also, as per the image you have shown, you are not seeing "that only the first value in the Constant block's array is output from it".  The viewer clearly shows that you are viewing the value of `Constant 1(1,1)`, that is the first element in the signal.  The other 3 values output from the constant block and the Multiply block are clearly indicated in the viewer, you just haven't selected them for viewing.